# $me = $facebook->api('/me'); returns empty string

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This piece of code used to work as expected, but now it seems i can't retrieve the user name the same way:

```
 $uid = $facebook->getUser(); // returns the facebook id of the user
 $me = $facebook->api('/me'); // returns empty. why?
```

Due some facebook api updates i had to change the getSession from:

```
$session = $facebook->getUser();
```

to

```
$session = $facebook->getUser()>0;
```

So how to retrieve the user name in facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how to retrieve the user name in facebook?

**What about this :**

```
$pageContent = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/USERID');
$parsedJson  = json_decode($pageContent);
echo $parsedJson->name;
```

Comment: That helped. i didn't know that i could jut do it like that! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Facebook use CURL for send request to server, maybe curl on your server not work or curl_exec is disabled