# $facebook->api('/me') always returns null

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$me = $facebook->api(‘/me’); returns empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147484/me-facebook-api-me-returns-empty-string)

I try create one facebook app. I use facebook sdk for php. but when I get userprofile by $facebook->api('me') is always return null value. I don't understand where I had mistaked? My code below. Everyone help me. Thanks a lot!

$fbconfig['appid' ] = "3256............................";//id của bạn

$fbconfig['secret'] = "18cadb0.....................";//secret của bạn

```
$user            =   null; //facebook user uid
try{
    include_once "src/facebook.php";
}
catch(Exception $o){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($o);
    echo '</pre>';
}

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'fileUpload' => true
));

$user       = $facebook->getUser();//Lấy thông tin người dùng

$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => 'email,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown'
        )
);//Yêu cầu login với các quyền cần thiết

if ($user) {//Kiểm tra user và lấy thông tin user
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    echo $user.'<br />';
    var_dump($user_profile);
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the value of $facebook->getUser() ?

Comment: I had got the value of $facebook->getUser(). This is a series of numbers

Comment: That series of nuymbers must be the facebook id, verify that. Then, simply use $facebook->api('/me')

Comment: How to verify that? My code above. You can see it. And show me what I must do?

Comment: Say "ID" is that number, just run in the browser: facebook.com/ID

Comment: I try echo $user=$facebook->getUser(). And I saw '100001104792939'. And I run in the browser 'facebook.com/100001104792939'. The browser redirected to faceboom.com/reddevil

Comment: if its so, $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me'); must return the array. try print_r($user_profile)

Comment: I didn't see something when I try print_r($user_profile). When I try var_dump($user_profile) I saw 'NULL'

Comment: add the access token parameter to "/me?access_token=" . You can get the access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken()

Comment: $access_token=$facebook->getAccessToken();

Comment: $userprofile=$facebook->api('/me?access_token='.$access_token). Result is null _ _!

Comment: try here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me. If still not works, there's some bug

Comment: Bug                                                                 {
  "error": {
    "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2500
  }
}

Comment: Learn the basics first, else the comments will be endless. Start from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
$pageContent = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/USERID');
$parsedJson  = json_decode($pageContent);
echo $parsedJson->name;
```

Comment: I tried it. I see current user's name. Continue What I must do to get full information of current user

Comment: I didn't use $facebook->api...What I must do?